# red5 Build hls-plugin and the example failure

Tags: java, maven, red5, http-live-streaming, red5-hls-plugin

I have tried to excute `mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true` in hls-plugin and the example. But it failed to connect and I can't download red5-server-1.0.2.SNAPSHOT.jar.

Here is what I get when I run the `mvn` command :

```
D:\DataAsia\LivingData\red5-hls-plugin-master\example>mvn eclipse:eclipse
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.red5:hlsapp:war:1.1
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.red5:hls-plugin:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/hls-plugin-1.1.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 436, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.red5:hls-plugin:jar refers to a non-existing file D:\DataAsia\LivingData\red5-hls-plugin-master\example\lib\hls-plugin-1.1.jar @ line 436, column 25
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building hlsapp 1.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-eclipse-plugin:2.7:eclipse (default-cli) @ hlsapp >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-eclipse-plugin:2.7:eclipse (default-cli) @ hlsapp <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-eclipse-plugin:2.7:eclipse (default-cli) @ hlsapp ---
Downloading: http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/org/red5/red5-server/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/repository/org/red5/red5-server/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.red5:red5-server:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to Red5 (http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/repository): Connection to http://red5.googlecode.com refused
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.red5:red5-server:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to Xuggle (http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/): Connection to http://xuggle.googlecode.com refused
Downloading: http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/repository/org/red5/red5-server/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/red5-server-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
Downloading: http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/org/red5/red5-server/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/red5-server-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Using Eclipse Workspace: null
[WARNING] An error occurred during dependency resolution.
Failed to retrieve org.red5:hls-plugin-1.1
Caused by: System artifact: org.red5:hls-plugin:jar:1.1:system not found in path: D:\DataAsia\LivingData\red5-hls-plugin-master\example\lib\hls-plugin-1.1.jar

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command:
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.red5 -DartifactId=hls-plugin -Dversion=1.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.red5 -DartifactId=hls-plugin -Dversion=1.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

Path to dependency:
1) org.red5:hlsapp:war:1.1
2) org.red5:hls-plugin:jar:1.1

org.red5:hls-plugin:jar:1.1

[INFO] Unable to read jar manifest from D:\DataAsia\LivingData\red5-hls-plugin-master\example\lib\hls-plugin-1.1.jar
[INFO] Resource directory's path matches an existing source directory. Resources will be merged with the source directory src/main/java
[INFO] File D:\DataAsia\LivingData\red5-hls-plugin-master\example.project already exists.
Additional settings will be preserved, run mvn eclipse:clean if you want old settings to be removed.
[INFO] Wrote Eclipse project for "hlsapp" to D:\DataAsia\LivingData\red5-hls-plugin-master\example.
[INFO]
Javadoc for some artifacts is not available.
Please run the same goal with the -DdownloadJavadocs=true parameter in order to check remote repositories for javadoc.
List of artifacts without a javadoc archive:
o ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.0.13
o ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.0.13
o org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
o javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5
o junit:junit:4.10
o org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
o net.sourceforge.groboutils:groboutils-core:5
o org.apache.mina:mina-core:2.0.7
o org.apache.mina:mina-integration-beans:2.0.7
o org.apache.mina:mina-integration-jmx:2.0.7
o ognl:ognl:3.0.5
o javassist:javassist:3.11.0.GA
o org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
o org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.5
o org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.5
o org.springframework:spring-aop:3.1.4.RELEASE
o aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
o org.springframework:spring-asm:3.1.4.RELEASE
o org.springframework:spring-beans:3.1.4.RELEASE
o org.springframework:spring-core:3.1.4.RELEASE
o org.springframework:spring-context:3.1.4.RELEASE
o org.springframework:spring-expression:3.1.4.RELEASE
o org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.1.4.RELEASE
o org.springframework:spring-test:3.1.4.RELEASE
o org.springframework:spring-web:3.1.4.RELEASE

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:08.655s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 28 16:24:37 CST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
D:\DataAsia\LivingData\red5-hls-plugin-master\example>mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.red5:hlsapp:war:1.1
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.red5:hls-plugin:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/hls-plugin-1.1.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 436, column 25
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.red5:hls-plugin:jar refers to a non-existing file D:\DataAsia\LivingData\red5-hls-plugin-master\example\lib\hls-plugin-1.1.jar @ line 436, column 25
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building hlsapp 1.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/org/red5/red5-server/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/repository/org/red5/red5-server/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.red5:red5-server:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to Red5 (http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/repository): Connection to http://red5.googlecode.com refused
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.red5:red5-server:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to Xuggle (http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/): Connection to http://xuggle.googlecode.com refused
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.red5:red5-server:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/repository was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Red5 has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.red5:red5-server:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to Red5 (http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/repository): Connection to http://red5.googlecode.com refused
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.red5:red5-server:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Xuggle has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.red5:red5-server:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to Xuggle (http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/): Connection to http://xuggle.googlecode.com refused
Downloading: http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/repository/org/red5/red5-server/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/red5-server-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
Downloading: http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/org/red5/red5-server/1.0.2-SNAPSHOT/red5-server-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:04.798s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jun 28 16:26:08 CST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hlsapp: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.red5:hlsapp:war:1.1: Failed to collect dependencies at org.red5:red5-server:jar:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.red5:red5-server:jar:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.red5:red5-server:pom:1.0.2-SNAPSHOT from/to Red5 (http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/repository): Connection to http://red5.googlecode.com refused: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
D:\DataAsia\LivingData\red5-hls-plugin-master\example>
```

Comment: Fairly certain that we never published the hls-plugin to sonatype nor central.  Xuggler is for sure no longer alive and googlecode is history.

Comment: thanks,and i have found some details in [here](https://dryize.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/red5-red5-hls-plugin-and-hls-streaming/).Besides,Officials suggests me to refd5 pro.Thank you all the same!